# setinterval() slows down website

Tags: jquery

I have a litle livescore page and I use setinterval function to display data in divs without refreshing. The problem is that website needs more time, and cpu ussage i think, to display data. What can I do to improve code performance?

data.php file

```
<?php   
$server = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root"); 
$db = mysqli_select_db($server, "tenisapt");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM meciurilive WHERE id = '1'";
$result = mysqli_query($server, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sset1j1 = $row['Set1j1'];
$sset1j2 = $row['Set1j2'];
$sset2j1 = $row['Set2j1'];
$sset2j2 = $row['Set2j2'];
$sset3j1 = $row['Set3j1'];
$sset3j2 = $row['Set3j2'];
$sset4j1 = $row['Set4j1'];
$sset4j2 = $row['Set4j2'];
$sset5j1 = $row['Set5j1'];
$sset5j2 = $row['Set5j2'];

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span id="j1s1"><?php echo $sset1j1;?></span>
<span id="j2s1"><?php echo $sset1j2;?></span>
<span id="j1s2"><?php echo $sset2j1;?></span>
<span id="j2s2"><?php echo $sset2j2;?></span>
<span id="j1s3"><?php echo $sset3j1;?></span>
<span id="j2s3"><?php echo $sset3j2;?></span>
<span id="j1s4"><?php echo $sset4j1;?></span>
<span id="j2s4"><?php echo $sset4j2;?></span>
<span id="j1s5"><?php echo $sset5j1;?></span>
<span id="j2s5"><?php echo $sset5j2;?></span>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php file

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#showj1s1').load('data.php #j1s1');
            $('#showj2s1').load('data.php #j2s1');
            $('#showj1s2').load('data.php #j1s2');
            $('#showj2s2').load('data.php #j2s2');
            $('#showj1s3').load('data.php #j1s3');
            $('#showj2s3').load('data.php #j2s3');
            $('#showj1s4').load('data.php #j1s4');
            $('#showj2s4').load('data.php #j2s4');
            $('#showj1s5').load('data.php #j1s5');
            $('#showj2s5').load('data.php #j2s5')
        }, 7500);
    });
```

Comment: Try, instead of doing multiples loads, use $.ajax to get the full `$row` array at once.

Comment: Yes as mentioned above only one single call should be made to get the data from data.php not so many calls. This will definitely slow down the client machines.

Comment: Same as previous answers, do just one call with Ajax to your PHP, and handle the display after coming back to your JS :). Furthermore, you should exit your ajax if there is an error occuring, here you just echo the error (for debug purpose I assume ?)

Comment: I understand, but can you show me on code how to make that single call? I am not as good on ajax

Comment: You have to cut / paste your PHP code in another script php, and then make an ajax call to this script. Everything the php script will echo will be return into "response" variable. Example : `https://jsfiddle.net/psa4h2z1/2/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the use of ajax is the best way to do this, in your setIntervall function call a script that return the HTML of each span with ajax, at the ajax call success you have to refresh the body with the new html

Read the documentation at [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)